# Just so you know: Per deployed webapp SLF4J & Logback in JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: jboss7.x, slf4j, logback

Until the JBoss team will support per deployment slf4j logging you can do this for webapps:

- Put a logback.xml in src/main/resources/ (or WEB-INF/classes/ for non-maven2 projects):

  ```
  <configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="3 seconds" debug="true">
      <contextName>[webAppName]</contextName>
      <include file="/opt/jboss/includedConfig.xml"/>
  </configuration>
  ```

  The includedConfig.xml can now be modified at runtime which saves redeployments for logging changes
- Put a jboss-deployment-structure.xml in WEB-INF:

  ```
  <jboss-deployment-structure>
      <deployment>
          <exclusions>
              <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
              <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
              <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
              <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub"/>
              <module name="org.jboss.logmanager"/>
              <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j"/>
              <module name="org.slf4j"/>
          </exclusions>
      </deployment>
  </jboss-deployment-structure>
  ```

  You need to exclude commons-logging & log4j only if you're including jcl-over-slf4j & log4j-over-slf4j

Comment: Just so you know that per-deployment logging is upstream so it will be in the next release.

Comment: Per-deployment logging ticket: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-514

Comment: Still the only solution - in 8 days JBoss 7.1.1 Final will have been the latest version for 1 year :)

Comment: @Torben, there is a next version out, but the new naming has made things about as confusing as you could possibly make it.  Some of the explanation is given here: http://www.openlogic.com/blog/bid/283299/Where-is-JBoss-7-2-0-Final

Comment: @TorbenVesterager This is not a question. You should posted it as proper question and later answer it yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer